# Debugging PLV8 in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, debugging, plugins, plpgsql, plv8

Some time ago I asked for [disadvantages of using PLV8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893409/plv8-disadvantages-or-limitations) within PostgreSQL Functions and Triggers. In the meantime I use a mixed szenario with plpgSQL and love it. But - as mentioned - debugging has less options with PLV8. So far I understand the plugin_debugger works only with plpgSQL. Is there anybody outside who found a nice way to do PLV8 debugging in another way then using masses of annoying `plv8.elog(NOTICE, 'this happens with my variable')`? Maybe any third party tool or secret plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Remote debugging is no longer supported in pl/v8.

It was available in pl/v8 up to version 1.4.x (see [#131](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues/131#issuecomment-237711101)). Notable missing features in older releases include ES6.

**Workarounds**

If you need to debug ES6/7 code using pl/v8 1.4.x you could transpile it using Traceur.

---

From the [documentation](http://pgxn.org/dist/plv8/doc/plv8.html#Remote.debugger) for 1.4.x:

> PL/v8 supports v8 remote debugger. You need to enable it at the compile time to pass `ENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT` to make. make static will automatically turns it on. If enabled, and once PL/v8 module is loaded (and the execution engine is initialized, PL/v8 accepts a remote debugger connection. If you have d8 from v8 package, run with `--remote-debug --debug-port=35432` to attach the functions. If you want to change the remote debugger port, there is a GUC `plv8.debugger_port` to set the port number. You can also try debugger statement inside functions to set a breakpoint. For more details of v8 remote debugger, see v8 documentation.

If you're not familiar with debugging JavaScript (or v8) that might be a bit much to handle.

If you're interested in the low-level features of the debugging protocol, [check this out](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Debugging-Protocol).

To step through code might be some leg work, but [here is a starting point](https://code.google.com/archive/p/chromedevtools/wikis/FeatureDebugOnRealFiles.wiki) for how that would be done.

If you were looking for a complete off-the-shelf solution or step-by-step tutorial I'm not sure that there is one specific to PL/v8.

I haven't personally tried any of these to debug PL/v8, however, it's possible one may connect and more or less work as expected: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugging-clients